# Is there an async way of knowing a file has changed?

Tags: c++, file, unix, filesystems, posix

I would like to asynchronously monitor a file for any changes. That is I would like to have a call back (possibly from kernel) in my program when the file has been modified/deleted. The file is just a plain text file. I know one can do this using a polling mechanism, but I am looking for an event based solution. I read about inotify, but looks like it needs patching of my kernel.

If the solution is POSIX compliant, its even better.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Inotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) was merged to the Linux kernel way back in 2005, so unless you're in a *very* old system, you should be able to use it out of the box.

I don't think there exists a POSIX compliant solution for this. Mac OS X has [FSEvents](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/FSEvents_ProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Also check the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/7/inotify) for inotify.

EDIT:

Don't know about your constraints and/or requirements, but there is also [GFileMonitor](http://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GFileMonitor.html) if you use Glib (the C++ binding is [glibmm](http://developer.gnome.org/glibmm/stable/classGio_1_1File.html#ab8e14809f330ddd58e628c96921cd987)) and [QFileSystemWatcher](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.7/qfilesystemwatcher.html) is you use Qt. Those are probably more cross-platform friendly.

Comment: Here is a small example of using `inotify` to wait for file to appear, if it helps - http://lazarenko.me/tips-and-tricks/waiting-for-the-file-to-appear-in-linux-using-inotify
It can be easily tuned to watch for file changes.

Answer (score 1):

SGI's [fam](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_alteration_monitor) has been ported to several Unixes. There's also [gamin](http://people.gnome.org/~veillard/gamin/).

Answer (score 0):

1)

write a device driver that creates a file called /dev/special_file.

symlink your plain text file to /dev/special file

intercept the low-level read/write operations to modify the real text file, called /path/to/text.txt, then generate the callback via signals or some type of interprocess comm to whatever process you want.

2)

have a process open your text file and just sit and wait. use select() to detect when that file has been modified, then do callback routine.